# Which makes a better integration with spring: Drools and Activiti Or Drools and JBPM

Tags: activiti

Need to undertand he factors to be consider while choosing between the workflow engines to be integrated with Spring and Drools.

Comment: IMO, rule engines should be seen as a service to the bpm engine. Sure, tight integration can be useful when your process is very well known and stable but otherwise the different lifecycles of  the process itself and rulesets may become a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am using Spring+Activiti+Drools in my application and I faced **no integration issues**.

From Activiti.org

> Activiti or jBPM, which should I use in my next project? Activiti
>   builds further on the huge experience that we build up from founding
>   jBPM till the Process Virtual Machine design in jBPM 4.  In Activiti
>   we now have united very skilled and talented people and companies to
>   build the next generation BPM technology.  BPMN 2.0 will be the future
>   of BPM and we have the know-how to bring these features in a developer
>   friendly manner.  Activiti's dedicated focus on BPMN 2.0 enables us to
>   deliver a future proof BPM and workflow solution.
>
> Given that we spend a lot of effort building jBPM 4 and that we were
>   very proud of the results, we regret that a jBPM 4 is discontinued as
>   indicated by JBoss
>
> https://community.jboss.org/blogs/mark.little/2010/04/23/the-future-of-workflow-in-jboss
>   "It is fair to say that there was expectation that jBPM 4 would appear
>   in a version of the SOA Platform as a replacement for jBPM 3. With the
>   changes to the jBPM project team and the next steps in unifying our
>   efforts in this area across projects, it is not going to happen."
>
> Activiti will **not** suffer from a single company vulnerability.  We're
>   extremely happy that Alfresco gave us the opportunity to develop
>   Activiti with an intend to make it an Apache project.  Core at the
>   Apache foundation's value is the continuity of projects and
>   guaranteeing that it stays true the community.  So one of the
>   requirements is that multiple companies have to be actively involved
>   in the community of a project.   **From the start, SpringSource is**
>   **joining** this initiative so we are well on our way to ensure Activiti
>   will have a long life that is not under the full control of a single
>   person or company.

And

> **Activiti BPM Platform :**  Activiti is a light-weight workflow and Business
>   Process Management (BPM) Platform targeted at business people,
>   developers and system admins. Its core is a super-fast and rock-solid
>   BPMN 2 process engine for Java. It's open-source and distributed under
>   the Apache license. Activiti runs in any Java application, on a
>   server, on a cluster or in the cloud. **It integrates perfectly with**
>   **Spring**, it is extremely lightweight and based on simple concepts.